# How to break/filter $scope value into two different $scopes?

Tags: angularjs

I have 10 data in my $scope.Company = 10 items. I want to split records into two different scopes ($scope.companyA and $scope.companyB) and then i will bind those records into cascaded dropdown. Do you have any idea ? How can i achieve this ?

My records are like: -

My records are like: -

```
ColA   ColB  ColC
A       AA    NULL
B       A      Test
C       B      Test2
```

Comment: Show us some code, the json you are trying to split, anything. This question is very unclear.

Comment: @AlexD i have mentioned list of records i am getting from Web API. Records have three columns. In dropdown 1 i have to bind the row where ColC = NULL, in dropdown 2 i have to bind those records where ColB has the value of ColA

Comment: Show us some of the list, a few items or something. You pasted a table but it doesn't indicate much.

Comment: JSON is: - [
  {
    "Value": "03190F10",
    "ParentValue": "",
    "displayValue": "School"
  },
  {
    "Value": "32CFC4C7",
    "ParentValue": "79CF4F14",
    "displayValue": "Service"
  },
  {
    "Value": "360A3825",
    "ParentValue": "32CFC4C7",
    "displayValue": "ticket"
  },
  {
    "Value": "79CF4F14",
    "ParentValue": "03190F10",
    "displayValue": "Customer"
  },
  {
    "Value": "Blank",
    "ParentValue": "",
    "displayValue": "(Select)"
  }

Comment: I am storing JSON in $scope.Company. and now i want to split that JSON on behalf of parent value

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an array and you want to split it into 2 arrays.

```
$scope.company = [ 
    { "Value": "03190F10", "ParentValue": "", "displayValue": "School" }, 
    { "Value": "32CFC4C7", "ParentValue": "79CF4F14", "displayValue": "Service" }, 
    { "Value": "360A3825", "ParentValue": "32CFC4C7", "displayValue": "ticket" },
    { "Value": "79CF4F14", "ParentValue": "03190F10", "displayValue": "Customer" }, 
    { "Value": "Blank", "ParentValue": "", "displayValue": "(Select)" }];

$scope.company2 = $scope.company.slice(0, parseInt($scope.company.length / 2)); // take first half
$scope.company3 = $scope.company.slice(parseInt($scope.company.length / 2), $scope.company.length); // take second half
```

Comment: No i have JSON like [ { "Value": "03190F10", "ParentValue": "", "displayValue": "School" }, { "Value": "32CFC4C7", "ParentValue": "79CF4F14", "displayValue": "Service" }, { "Value": "360A3825", "ParentValue": "32CFC4C7", "displayValue": "ticket" }, { "Value": "79CF4F14", "ParentValue": "03190F10", "displayValue": "Customer" }, { "Value": "Blank", "ParentValue": "", "displayValue": "(Select)" }

Comment: doesn't matter, you can have objects as the items, will still work. added your json to my answer...

Comment: But my problem is how can i filter the row in angular where column of row have null value :/